# node_mass_update will not update field

Tags: nodes

Cannot get `node_mass_update();` to update Votes field. `$node_ids` is an array of node ids and `$votes` is a number.

```
    $updates = array('field_votes' => $votes);

    node_mass_update($node_ids,$updates);
```

My module fires and it tells me that nodes are being updated and gives me a progress bar, but the fields in the nodes are not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used (or even seen) that function before, but following the trail down to [`_node_mass_update_helper()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.admin.inc/function/_node_mass_update_helper/6), I think you need to use a format like this:

```
$updates = array('field_votes' => array(0 => array('value' => $votes)));
```

That array format is the standard way to update CCK fields in Drupal 6, and since the helper function does this:

```
foreach ($updates as $name => $value) {
  $node->$name = $value;
}
```

immediately before calling `node_save()`, I think that's what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks! Got it to work with

$updates = array('field_votes' => array('und' => array(0 => array('value' => floor($votes)))));

Answer (score 0):

I've never used (or even seen) that function before, but following the trail down to `_node_mass_update_helper()`, I think you need to use a format like this:

```
$updates = array('field_votes' => array(0 => array('value' => $votes)));
```

That array format is the standard way to update CCK fields in Drupal 6, and since the helper function does this:

Comment: Hi @user72602, welcome to Drupal Answers. It looks like your answer got cut off. Could you please complete it before it faces deletion due to low quality? Thanks!